# php file uploads' size

Tags: php

do we have any size issue with the file uploads that we perform in php using 
$_file[upload][name]? is there any restriction for the file upload using this ??? juz need to know ..

Comment: is there any upper limit for the upload size?

Comment: are you using your own hosting? or provided hosting? because if you do not host yourself, chances are there is no php.ini on your ftp. If this is the case I can help you further, then comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your php.ini

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

and (added after suggestions from others below)

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 8M
```

Comment: Don't forget post_max_size as well. It doesn't matter that upload_max_filesize=2G if post_max_size=16k

Comment: @Mark, your remark is incorrect, altough uploaded files are part of post data. PHP will allow, and handle correctly, upload_max_filesize=1G with post_max_size=2M. You'll get 1G files through, but otherwise post data is limited to 2m.

Comment: There's also server-side limits, such as Apache's LimitRequestBody on top of all this.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit maximum file uploaded size (you should change appropriate directives in your `php.ini` file). There are no other ways to limit uploaded file size.

```
upload_max_filesize = 1M //Maximum size of uploaded file
max_post_size = 1M //Maximum size of whole POST request
```

Comment: Actually the quota of disk space avaialable is also a limit ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also change limits in .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is restricted specifically by upload_max_filesize and also more generally by post_max_size settings in your php.ini.