# upload multiple photos per and assign them to one userid in the database

Tags: php, mysql, upload

i am building an ad site that allows users to upload multiple photos per ad, how do i get this to work? i am new to php

```
<?php echo $error_msg; ?>

<?php
    include_once "connection.php";

    if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

    $errors= array();

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  

        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload_data (`postid`,`file_name`,`file_size`,`file_type`) VALUES('$postid','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type')")or die (mysql_error());

        $desired_dir="uploads";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir);                
            }
            mysql_query($sql);          
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: It would help if you mention the problem you are facing. I see several things that could be causing a problem but I am not sure if they do in your case.

Comment: It's precisely for issues like this that I use a readymade module for handling all this. FWIW, I use Gallery3, because it's free and relatively easy to customize (although it gets a bit 'EAV', which isn't nice)

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem encountered when trying to upload multiple files is the upload_max_filesize and the max_post_size in your php.ini file.

If you have no problems uploading a series of very small images, then this will be your problem.

This quesion: [php file uploads' size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354042/php-file-uploads-size/3354070#3354070) discusses the issue effectively.

You should also consider echoing the $_FILES['files']['error'] which will often be instructive.  The [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) explains the codes.

Don't forget to check that you have included the correct call in your HTML FORM element too:

```
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='myfile.php'>
```

Make sure you have not specified an undersized max_file_size in your HTML form too.

I suggest that you don't prohibit large file uploads but rather you resize any overlarge images in your script.  This will help your users substantially.

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is what the table looks like right now table 1 .............. userid table 2 ................. postid foreign key: userid table 3 ............. picid foreign key: postid ..............but picid doesnt read postid as a foregin key..no 
this is when the user is ready to create the ad
so page one: the ad
page 2: upload pics
page 3 :view ad
page 4: send to list of ads.
i and having a problem with page 2
i have the other pages working 
it's just i cant get the pics to tie back to page one which is the ad 
in the database

Comment: the problem is how do i upload mulitple photos and then apply them to a signle id in the database